# Why the photos are not loading by element.src = '...' or setAtribute

Tags: javascript, html, src

These paths work in html.

The path changes in a good way, but the photos don't load

catalogs and files:

*index.html*

**img**/img-1.png/img-2.png/img-3.png

**src**/js/*app.js*

```
img.src = 'img/img-2.png';
img.setAttribute('src', 'img/img-2.png');
```

Comment: Hey Daniel. when does the src attribute change ? with what event ?

Comment: I think you would need to give the relative path to the images i.e. './img/img-2.png'

Comment: "the photos don't load" What does the network request panel of your dev-tools say about this?

Comment: could you put sample code on code-pen / fiddle and post the link here.

Comment: `setAttribute` should work.... Check for directory path, check in console are you getting any error? check in network tab whether code is requesting the image or not

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 and check the Image Url.
I think this would be img.setAttribute('src', 'some path/img/img-2.png');

Good Luck.